# Generating odd even numbers using 2 threads via wait notify?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, synchronized, notify

I am trying to generate odd even numbers using 2 threads via wait notify.
But it is only printing 0.

Could someone please explain why it is so.

Below is my code:

```
package waitNotify2;

class Odd implements Runnable {

    Object lock;
    volatile Integer ai;

    public Odd(Object lock, Integer ai) {
        super();
        this.lock = lock;
        this.ai = ai;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            while(true) {
                while(ai % 2 == 0) {
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(ai + " ");
                ai++;
                lock.notify();
            }
        }
    }

}

class Even implements Runnable {

    Object lock;
    volatile Integer ai;

    public Even(Object lock, Integer ai) {
        super();
        this.lock = lock;
        this.ai = ai;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            while(true) {
                while(ai % 2 == 1) {
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(ai + " ");
                ai++;
                lock.notify();
            }
        }
    }

}

public class PrintOddEven2 {

    // Driver Code
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object o = new Object();
        Integer i = 0;
        Odd odd = new Odd(o,i);
        Even even = new Even(o,i);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(odd);

        Thread t2 = new Thread(even);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to generate odd even numbers using 2 threads via wait notify. But it is only printing 0.  Could someone please explain why it is so.

You problem is that the 2 threads are both incrementing `ai` but they are not sharing the same variable.  So when the even thread spits out `0` and notifies the `lock`, the odd thread wakes up but it's copy of `ai` is still 0 so it goes back to sleep.

One way to fix this would be to pass in an `AtomicInteger` instead of the `Integer` class.  Then when the `Even` thread does an `ai.incrementAndGet()` and the `Odd` thread does a `ai.get()` it would see the changes to `ai`.

If you didn't want to use that class then you will need to write a `MutableInteger` class if you want them to share the same variable.

Couple other comments:

- Your `lock` field should be `final`.  Really all fields should be final if possible but with threaded programs, `final` is important as a rule.
- You could write `Odd` and `Even` as the same class and pass in the expected value of `ai.get() % 2`.
- There is an implied `super();` that happens in constructors so it can be removed.  The only time you need to have it specified explicitly is if there are multiple constructors in the base class.
- When you are catching `InterruptedException`, you should [always reinterrupt the thread](https://www.baeldung.com/java-interrupted-exception#2-restore-the-interrupt) in the catch with `Trread.currentThread().interrupt()`.